# What is the best way to keep updated with status of hechsheirim in Israel?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, how-to, beit-din-court, modern-times, state-of-israel

There are many halachic (and sociopolitical, agricultural, religious, economical, etc.) kashrut issues pertinent to Israel alone, leading to a great variety of challenges that kashrut authorities face. This has lead to great diversity in the application of halacha in this field.

There are also authorities from different regions in Israel which deal with these challenges in different ways and pasken strictly/leniently for wide ranging reasons. Israel's kashrut industry spans nationwide and as the industry accelerates, new challenges are faced and the kashrut status of items can often vary.

Some examples being: status of meats changing from Rabbanut to Mehadrin (and vice versa), kashrut authorities changing from otzar beit din to heter mechira nationwide (during shemitta year), changes in ingredients suppliers, changes in fruit/vegetable infestations (e.g. see [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/37488/can-vegetables-fruit-be-uncheckable)), dairy products changing status from chalav Israel to chalav akum, etc.

In order for one to be halachically consistent, what is the best way to keep updated with such changes?

Comment: Your first example is quite different from the latter two, as it doesn't refer to well-defined halachik categories.

Comment: @DoubleAA many want to be consistent in what they eat. Mehadrin tends to be stricter (and some would hold it more 'reliable'), although not being exactly defined (since different Mehadrin/Rabbanut establishments can practice very differently) it is enough of a status change, for people looking for consistency, to opt to eat it or not based on this

Comment: I know what it is. It is vague. It is only enough for consistency if your consistency isn't that consistent.

Answer (score 4):

[Kosharot](https://www.kosharot.co.il/) is a website dedicated to educating consumers on Kashrut issues in Israel. They publish [regular updates](https://www.kosharot.co.il/index2.php?id=60&lang=HEB) which might be exactly what you are looking for.

For an interesting podcast on the state of *kashrut* in Israel, see [here](http://podcast.headlinesbook.com/e/12619-kashrus-in-eretz-yisroel-and-kashrus-part-iii/), including R Moshe Katz who leads Kosharot as the first person being interviewed.